# What kind of pan works best with a waterbath?

Tags: equipment, cheesecake

Whenever I bake cheesecake or flan, my springform pan always leaks into the water bath or vice/versa.  Is there a better type of pan to use when baking with a water bath?

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16208/how-do-i-wrap-a-spring-form-pan-in-foil-so-it-doesnt-leak-when-i-bake-in-a-wate/16330#16330

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much have to use the sprinform pan with cheesecakes, otherwise you can't get the cheesecake out of the pan. If you don't care to remove the cheesecake from the pan whole, then you can use anything you want—a deep cake pan would work well, for example.

There are two ways to help keep the springform pan from leaking:

1. Wrap the sprinform pan (the entire bottom, and up the sides) in aluminum foil. Use two layers of foil, especially if you're using the cheap thin stuff.
2. Find a round cake pan slightly larger than your sprinform pan (say, a 10" wide, 3" deep pan with a 9" springform). Sit the springform pan inside the cake pan, then put the cake pan in the bain-marie (so the water isn't actually touching the springform pan). This suggestion comes from [Cooks Illustrated](http://www.cooksillustrated.com/howto/detail.asp?docid=30362) (sorry, paywall), who tested this and found the small gap doesn't matter.

If you're doing a lot of cheesecakes, then you can get a 10"x3" cake pan on Amazon for $10–15.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a round silicone baking pan.

[image]

Comment: It'd be impossible to get the cheesecake out of it.

Comment: @derobert no, it is really easy to get the cheesecake out of it. This thing is flexible and non-stick, you just peel it off the cake.

Comment: @rumtscho Interesting. You can do that without smashing to sides of the cheesecake?

Comment: @derobert  Yes. They work very well. Here is a random site confirming this: http://www.favoritefreezerfoods.com/best-cheesecake-recipe.html