# Springform pan vs. regular cake pan

Tags: cake

Can a regular cake such as from a cake mix be baked in a springform pan?  If so, will the results be the same as a normal cake pan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely!

"Regular" or springform pans is in my experience partly a cultural difference: In Germany you might have trouble to find a non-springform pan.

As long as the diameter is the same, you can freely substitute one for the other.

There is *one exception*, though: Most springform pans aren't watertight, so for a [cheesecake](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24811/what-kind-of-pan-works-best-with-a-waterbath) in a water bath, you should either choose a regular pan (and face the trouble with unmolding) or see [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16208/how-do-i-wrap-a-spring-form-pan-in-foil-so-it-doesnt-leak-when-i-bake-in-a-wate/16330#16330) for how to tighten them.

Comment: Beeswax can be used to seal a springform

Comment: And, it's worth noting that you shouldn't assume the opposite is true... Some cakes benefit greatly from a springform and will not release easily from a standard pan.

Comment: @Catija which is what I guess to be the reason I have difficulties buying a non-springform pan here ^_^.