# Cheesecakes Baked in a Waterbath

Tags: baking

How do you keep a cheesecake from absorbing water baked in a waterbath?
I put four sheets of aluminum foil around my springform pan and it still leaks onto the crust.

Comment: see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/24811/67  ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16208/67 and maybe http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/55419/67